# Why would this mongo query be so slow?

Tags: javascript, performance, mongodb, optimization, mongodb-query

I'm trying to figure out how to handle this situation. Which eventually should be date ranges.

```
db.article_raw.count({
   "date": {$gt:ISODate("2015-07-08T00:00:00.000Z")},
   "searchTerms.term":"iPhone"
})
```

I have the following 3 indexes (which I know are repetitive, but I'm trying to figure it out)

```
{
   "date" : 1,
   "searchTerms.term" : 1
}

{
    "date" : 1
}

{
    "searchTerms.term" : 1
}
```

The data looks like

```
{
    title: "a cool title",
    date: ISODate("2015-07-09T11:58:36.000Z"),
    "searchTerms" : [ 
        {
            "term" : "According to Jim",
            "relevance" : "0.315"
        }, 
        {
            "term" : "iPhone",
            "relevance" : "0.057"
        }
   }
}
```

Lastly, here is the result of the explain() on the find() version of this.

```
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor date & search",
    "isMultiKey" : true,
    "n" : 275,
    "nscannedObjects" : 275,
    "nscanned" : 11022,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 16142,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 26889,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 1074,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 59548,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "date" : [ 
            [ 
                ISODate("2015-07-08T00:00:00.000Z"), 
                Date(9223372036854775807)
            ]
        ],
        "searchTerms.term" : [ 
            [ 
                "iPhone", 
                "iPhone"
            ]
        ]
    },
    "server" : "...",
    "filterSet" : false,
    "stats" : {
        "type" : "FETCH",
        "works" : 11023,
        "yields" : 1074,
        "unyields" : 1074,
        "invalidates" : 90,
        "advanced" : 275,
        "needTime" : 10746,
        "needFetch" : 1,
        "isEOF" : 1,
        "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
        "forcedFetches" : 0,
        "matchTested" : 0,
        "children" : [ 
            {
                "type" : "IXSCAN",
                "works" : 11022,
                "yields" : 1074,
                "unyields" : 1074,
                "invalidates" : 90,
                "advanced" : 275,
                "needTime" : 10746,
                "needFetch" : 0,
                "isEOF" : 1,
                "keyPattern" : "{ date: 1, searchTerms.term: 1 }",
                "isMultiKey" : 1,
                "boundsVerbose" : "field #0['date']: (new Date(1436313600000), new Date(9223372036854775807)], field #1['searchTerms.term']: [\"iPhone\", \"iPhone\"]",
                "yieldMovedCursor" : 0,
                "dupsTested" : 275,
                "dupsDropped" : 0,
                "seenInvalidated" : 0,
                "matchTested" : 0,
                "keysExamined" : 11022,
                "children" : []
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

If these indexes are correct, I don't see how this query takes 80 seconds to run.  There are close to a million articles in the system. And the result of this count is about 250.

Comment: You should consider using a `[searchTerms.term, date]` index; it is always preferable to perform exact matches before range matches.

Comment: Can you provide the results of a .explain(true)?

Comment: How much memory does the machine have and what version of mongo are you using.

Comment: Did you go through [performance tuning](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/transparent-huge-pages/) yet?

Comment: @ChrisHeald isn't that what is happening already?

Comment: @SeanClark Nope - your first clause is the date field, which is queried as a range. Field order in complex indices matters in mongo. You have the index [date, term] and want the index [term, date].

Comment: @ThrowsException 8gb version 2.6.9

Comment: So I updated the index and ran the query with search terms first. It took 10 seconds this time. So much better, but still too slow for actual use.

Comment: @MatthewAntolovich new explain here http://jsonfiddle.net/psb8t dates adjusted to be proper JSON for the formatter

Comment: ACTUALLY. the count was slow, but the find is fast now. thanks to @ChrisHeald. If you put the answer in, i'll mark it

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be expected behavior Sean in a large data set where index is create on date because of the high cardinality. MongoDB uses B(alance)-Tree indexes now if the column values have millions of different values (as date is precise till the millisecond and its high possibility that most of them are not same) then eventually though it uses Index its not giving any benefit of index in this case. 
Generally in this situation where you have to find the data based on some day range, its preferred to have one more column which contains only the date part where you apply the index and use that in your query criteria, this may help improving your performance drastically..

-$

Comment: Even for doing date ranges such as $gt this still applies?

Comment: Yes, in any kind of condition checks it has to travel and take decision which node to go....i mean, in $gt condition also the date index is used as also suggested by the explain plan but its useless because of high cardinality. Hashed indexes are the only one which is used for equality check and ignored in case of range check because they depends in hashed.

Comment: Also, now i see all comments..Chris solition is perfect, order of indexes r very imp., in your case it would first try to match the date which is slow because of high cardinality, and then the term however if u reverse the order then first it would immediately find the term iPhone and then in those limited dataset it would check the date condition which would surely be faster than what you were originally doing..... Still i would suggest to go via extra date only part n create a index in term:1, date_part:1, doing this would evn make ur search faster in much bigger dataset compare ur curnt one